Azure DevOps parameter object type with strong type
I have the issue with Azure DevOps pipeline parameters.
I have this code:
parameters:
- name: images
  type: objects
  default:
  - registry: docker.io
    repository: selenium/standalone-chrome
    tag: 120.0
#   tag: '120.0'
#   tag: "120.0"

and doing echo it produces:
- ${{ each image in parameters.images }}:
  - script: |
      echo ${{ image.registry }}/${{ image.repository }}:${{ image.tag }}

with 'docker.io/selenium/standalone-chrome:120' instead of '120.0'
When the tag is changed to 120.1 then the output is 'docker.io/selenium/standalone-chrome:120.1'
How the object type parameter properties can be strong typed? In this case '120.0' to be string?

modified my answer. now it can be auto trigger or manually trigger with the same result. just copy and try.

try to use "'120.0'" or '"120.0"' both works

Have you tried the workaround shared in my answer below? Is it working for you?  @Leszek

@BrightRan-MSFT we are adding manually double quotes when triggering the pipeline

@Leszek, If you apply the shared workaround, you do not need to manually add the double quotes every time, especially when you forget to add the double quotes.

I do not think you can use type: objects, and try below sample
parameters:
- name: images
  type: object
  default:
  - registry: docker.io
    repository: selenium/standalone-chrome
    tag: '"120.0"'

steps:
- ${{ each image in parameters.images }}:
  - script: |
      echo ${{ image.registry }}/${{ image.repository }}:${{ image.tag }}



The issue is with trigger the pipeline:

It removes double qoute from tag.

This issue seems only occurs when manually triggering the pipeline from the web UI. It looks like a defect on manual trigger from web UI. You can try to report this issue on Developer Community to ask for a fix on it.
When triggering the same pipeline via other ways that are not from the web UI, the issue does not occur, and the parameter value '120.0' can be recognized correctly.

Adding extra double/single quotes to surround the parameter value, such as tag: '"120.0"' or tag: "'120.0'", is not a good idea.

When manually triggering the pipeline from the web UI, it can display the right parameter value '120.0' only when print it using the script task.

However, when pass the parameter value as input on other tasks, such as Docker@2, the extra double/single quotes will be taken as part of the value, and cause "invalid tag"error on the task.


parameters:
- name: images
  type: object
  default:
  - registry: 'docker.io'
    repository: 'selenium/standalone-chrome'
    tag: '"120.0"'

steps:
- ${{ each image in parameters.images }}:
  - bash: |
      echo ${{ image.registry }}/${{ image.repository }}:${{ image.tag }}
      echo image.tag = ${{ image.tag }}
  
  - task: Docker@2
    displayName: 'Build image'
    inputs:
      containerRegistry: 'MyDockerHub'
      repository: '${{ image.repository }}'
      command: 'build'
      Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
      tags: ${{ image.tag }}



As workaround, you can first try check if the '.0' was missed from the parameter value, if so, add it back. Then pass the correct value to a pipeline variable. On tasks, use the pipeline variable to pass the value.
parameters:
- name: images
  type: object
  default:
  - registry: 'docker.io'
    repository: 'selenium/standalone-chrome'
    tag: '120.0'

jobs:
- ${{ each image in parameters.images }}:
  - job: build
    variables:
      ${{ if contains(image.tag, '.') }}:
        image_tag: '${{ image.tag }}'
      ${{ else }}:
        image_tag: '${{ image.tag }}.0'
    steps:
    - bash: |
        echo ${{ image.registry }}/${{ image.repository }}:$(image_tag)
        echo image_tag = $(image_tag)
    
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: 'Build image'
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: 'MyDockerHub'
        repository: '${{ image.repository }}'
        command: 'build'
        Dockerfile: '**/Ubuntu2204.Dockerfile'
        tags: $(image_tag)




Just as you said, I have re-test the scenario tags: $(image_tag) with '"120.0"' and "'120.0'" both throw errors. So it is not a elegant way.

The issue is that 120.0 is mapped to int and 120.1 works fine.

@Leszek, Yes, I know that "120.1" can work as expected. The workaround shared in my answer can add the missed ".0" when the parameter value is "xx.0". When the parameter value is "xx.1", "xx.2", "xx.3", etc.., it also can work as expected.

The issue is, that the tag can be anything from 'alpha-120.0', '120.1', to '120.0.0'

@Leszek, Based on my attempt, the issue occurs only when the tag/version number format is two segments "<xxx>.<xxx>" (e.g., 120.0). When the number format is "<xxx>-<xxx>.<xxx>" (e.g., alpha-120.0), "<xxx>.<xxx>.<xxx>" (e.g., 120.0.0), "<xxx>.<xxx>.<xxx>.<xxx>" (e.g., 120.0.0.0), or other formats, the issue does not occur.

@BrightRan-MSFT the issue is only with two segments with zero after dot ".0".

@Leszek, Yes, correct. As I mentioned previously, the issue only occurs with two segments. The workaround in my above answer can cover this situation, and also can let other situations work as normal.
